# Is there an IDE with explicit support for AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, ide, angularjs

I've tried WebStorm but there only seems to be a basic JavaScript support there, like in any other web IDE I have tried. I'm looking for something that would allow me to click-through from HTML pages to Controllers etc.

If the answer is "no" to this question, is there any other JavaScript framework similar to Angular that would have something like an Eclipse plugin or any other kind of explicit support in some IDE?

Comment: Could some kind moderator lease migrate this to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Did not test it but Codelobster seems to have an AngularJs plugin, too: http://codelobster.com/order.html

Answer (score 28):

John Lindquist says he'll make a plugin for WebStorm:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84299

Comment: I've tried the plugin; it's nice.  It provides intellisense for the AngularJS keywords.  It appears to be what John Lindquist is using in the AngularJS videos here: http://johnlindquist.com/

Comment: By the way, here's a link to the plugin along with some instructions on how to install it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/GyBSkDxZN9c

The installation is *very* easy -- literally just a handful of clicks.

Comment: In addition to John's plugin I'm maintaining a set of LiveTemplates for WebStorm in the GitHub repository: https://github.com/angularjs-livetpls/angularjs-webstorm-livetpls

Answer (score 25):

Visual Studio 2012 by far is the best. This [tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/04/12/video-tutorial-angularjs-fundamentals-in-60-ish-minutes.aspx) uses VS 2012 and was very helpful for me. There is also an [Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop) version that is free.

The tutorial helps you get started from ground up without the need to rely on plugins.

[Another great Angular JS project/tutorial using Visual Studio](https://github.com/DanWahlin/CustomerManagerStandard)

Comment: @Imrul, vmichael is insightfully correct here. VS 2012 does indeed support angular js development. While it was intended to extend .NET apps, it seems to be fully serviceable for purely angular development. I appreciate that you, unlike the other down-voter, left a msg, but please do your own research before slamming well-intentioned people.

Comment: VS is actually quite a good IDE for the web. I started to use it while working in a .NET environment, and was pleasantly surprised. For developing in Windows, it works well.

Comment: A bit of track but Visual Studio is one of the reasons I like programming .NET apps so much. Also for web apps, including AngularJS development (with some tweaks).

Answer (score 14):

Someone is working in NetBeans plugin for angular. You can see it here: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40296/angularjs-tools

Also for Microsoft VisualStudio
http://nuget.org/packages/AngularJsSeed/1.0.0-RC1

Comment: There is no way I am going to use NetBeans but thanks for the answer :)

Comment: So what exactly do you need the IDE for? I mean angularJS is just HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and most IDEs will consume that just fine. Not sure that having the autocomplete on the ng* is such a deal breaker?

Comment: Hi Misko, I would actually like to use the autocomplete for ng.js in Net Beans but it seems to ignore my plugin (already added un-minified library to my project). The benefit of this is that without the plugin Net Beans barks at you when trying to validate the HTML markup (ng-view etc.) Any ideas on this? Thanks for great lib! Edit: Hmm... Will probably ask that on the plugin site ;)

Comment: @MiskoHevery good IDE is very useful and a must. You need to track directives, filters, services (go-to-source). You want in one click from the html to go the matching controller.. you want good complication for the views (ng-directives and custom). Try to build a large-client-side app without a good IDE across a large team or even a medium one without IDE..

Answer (score 14):

AngularUI have written plugins that offer full AngularJS (and optionally AngularUI) IDE support for Sublime Text 2 & 3 and TextMate text editors.

Sublime Text 2 & 3
http://www.sublimetext.com/3

TextMate (Mac OS X only)
http://macromates.com/download

AngularUI IDE Plugins
Sublime - https://github.com/angular-ui/AngularJS-sublime-package
TextMate - https://github.com/angular-ui/AngularJS.tmbundle

You can get a complete setup guide for Sublime Text here (you'll be up and running in 5 mins tops):
http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/08/30/using-the-angularjs-package-for-sublime-text.aspx

When I'm developing early proof of concepts apps, I like to use DropBox to store my code so I can get access to everything at work and at home. Plus if you store your project in the `Public` folder, you can generate a publicly accessible url for your `.html` pages which will correctly render in the brower (i.e. correctly run your HTML, CSS & JS), essentially turning DropBox into a sort of limited hosting provider.

If you decide to use Sublime, you can download the portable version (no install required) & save that to DropBox too; this way you have access to all your code AND a full AngularJS IDE from wherever you use DropBox. Which basically means you have a full dev environment in the cloud. Pretty sweet!

Comment: Actually, Webstorm has support for AngularJS and many more Javascript libraries using something called "Typescript definitions". Here is how to enable from another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876863/how-do-i-enable-webstorm-intellisense-for-angularjs-when-writing-coffeescript

Answer (score 7):

There is now a Resharper plugin for angularjs  which means if you use resharper then Visual Studio becomes a great way to develop Angular too.

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/02/angularjs-support-for-resharper/

Also there is a debugging addon for chrome now:

http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/07/introducing-angularjs-batarang.html