# How do I enable Webstorm intellisense for AngularJS when writing CoffeeScript

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, webstorm

I have setup Webstorm to recognise and compile my coffeescript files.

I have installed the AngularJS plugin and can successfully write my controllers etc in plain old javascript.

When I try to write my angular related code in CoffeeScript however I do not get any IDE support: code-completion, intellisense etc.

As a sign that all is not well, the `angular` variable itself is not recognised, as shown in the image below.

[image]

**Question**: How do I enable support for AngularJS in CoffeeScript files?

Thanks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To fix the specific problem `Unresolved variable or type angular` you need to make sure the angular javascript libraries have been `Enabled` (see image below).

You do this via the WebStorm settings:

> File -> Settings -> Javascript -> Libraries

[image: Managing Javascript Libraries]

Here is the relevant help section: [Configuring JavaScript Libraries](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/configuring-javascript-libraries.html)

Comment: This is a good post, because regarding to Webstorm, http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/03/angularjs-workflow-in-webstorm/, this is activated when the library is loaded. Wich is NOT true.

Comment: For me, this isn't the solution. It does solve the `Unresolved variable or type angular` notification, but I never had issues because of this. My problem lies within the testing of using this `.coffee` file, it still fails on `ReferenceError: angular is not defined`

Answer (score 13):

With webstorm 10 you are going to go to the preferences window and from there select Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries. Then click the download button, select TypeScript community stubs from the dropdown at the top of the list, find angular and click download and install.

If you are using jshint be sure to go to the jshint settings find the Predefined option and add angular:true to suppress warnings.

Comment: Thanks for the WS10.0 instructions!  A minor clarification is that there are >10 angular items available for download and none are named "angular".  downloading "angularjs" worked for me.

Comment: The problem with TypeScript community stubs is that there have no JSDocs so if I cmd+click a function to go to its definition I have no documentation about how to use it

Comment: Is it possible to automatically use every library that is available in bower and/or npm?

Answer (score 3):

In WebStorm v.11

- go to "**Settings**" -> "**Plugins**" -> "**Browse repositories**".
- Search and install "**Angular Templates**".
- Profit

  [Settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ7C8.png)