# Enable angularjs html autocompletion in WebStorm

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, webstorm

I am using WebStorm 9 and I want to add autocompletion.  I'm having trouble setting up angularjs autocompletion in an HTML document (I can only set it up in a JavaScript file).  I have tried using the method from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876863/how-do-i-enable-webstorm-intellisense-for-angularjs-when-writing-coffeescript), but it didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to place angular.js file (debug version, uncompressed!) anywhere in your project - in the root directory, in subfolder - doesn't matter. Once the file is there, Angular support should become available. If this doesn't work immediately, try reopening the project/invalidating caches (File/Invalidate caches).
See http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/03/angularjs-workflow-in-webstorm/ for details.