# Webstorm IDE and AngularJS angular.module unresolved method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intellij-idea

I am using Webstorm IDE for an AngularJS project.

I have added AngularJS to the librairies and autocompletion etc. works just fine.

However, Webstorm IDE does not find the function angular.module() which is quite central. I have tried everything (reinstalling, etc.) but it still does not seem to work.

Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: Apparently it's a bug in WebStorm11 IDE  [Link to ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18924)

Comment: Totally ridiculous that JetBrains hasn't resolved this. It's like if the someobj.prototype wasn't recognized. Jeez.

Answer (score 15):

To date there has been no progress on the WebStorm IDS [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18924) referenced above by @AllYouCanEat86 so I am not sure if it should be fixed without adding libraries to WebStorm. Once I followed the advice given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29453242/799588) my issue was resolved and no longer got the warning in WebStorm.

In short go to `File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries` and download `angular` (used to be called `angularjs`) from the community stubs. It appears in the list as `angularjs-DefinitelyTyped` once it has been downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to reply to a comment yet, but @Precastic's solution worked for me using Webstorm 9.  Note that the library name is "angular", not "angularjs", however.

To be clear, that solution was:

> In short go to `File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries` and download  `angular` from the community stubs. It appears in the list as angular-DefinitelyTyped once it has been downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the only solution was to include AngularJS using a CDN as instructed on the [Jetbrains blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/03/angularjs-workflow-in-webstorm/).

You include the script tag like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```

And follow the instructions below:

> If you prefer to use a CDN, place the cursor over the highlight library name, hit Alt+Enter, and Download Library. This will set up a local library in WebStorm’s cache (not in your project) so WebStorm can access AngularJS methods, directives, etc for autocompletion and documentation lookup.