# intelliJ: Unresolved variable or type google

Tags: javascript, google-maps, intellij-idea

I'm using google maps API in a project, everithing works, but idea parser complains of

> Unresolved variable or type google

[image]

I've seen solutions like [How do I enable Webstorm intellisense for AngularJS when writing CoffeeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876863/how-do-i-enable-webstorm-intellisense-for-angularjs-when-writing-coffeescript) but as long as I can't download google maps library does not work for me

Any idea of how to make idea detect google?

Comment: did u imported supporting js files for google-maps?

Comment: @DIM not sure, how can I check it / do it?

Comment: To start with go through https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/google_maps_intro.asp. Once you imported in your file, and want IDE to recognize the google API ,u can follow the link you have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876863/how-do-i-enable-webstorm-intellisense-for-angularjs-when-writing-coffeescript

Comment: @DIM my map is working nice, and please, read my question, I cant download google maps library as angular or others, either I don't want to mix javascript and html.  Imports are done, working and in the right place, intelliJ idea config is not.